# Vue CLI 4.5 compile without 'js, css, fonts, images' directories

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I would like to compile files via Vue CLI 4.5 however I want to omit the asset folders like `js`,`css`,`img`,`fonts`.

This is how my vue.config.js file looks like right now. I tried to change the `publicPath` and `assetsDir` with no luck.

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
            ? "/newfolder/"
            : "/",
    assetsDir: "static"
}
```

Vue is trying to load everything from:

```
newfolder/static/js
newfolder/static/css
newfolder/static/img
newfolder/static/fonts
```

Is there a way to dump everything into the `static` folder in my case?

Comment: You'll need to jump into the [Webpack chain configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) to alter the `output` (for JS) and several rules (`images`, `svg`, `fonts`, etc) to configure the webpack generated file paths. Why do you need / want to do this anyway?

Comment: Thank you @Phil that sounds like a good way to approach things. I need to do it this way because I have to upload all assets to one endpoint that could not have any subfolders at all.